# why does wireless access point operates on link layer

Tags: networking, switch-statement

It's said in text book that, switches are unable to connect heterogeneous networks (networks with different link layer technology).

However, wireless access point do connects different networks (wireless and wired). Why people say it's a link layer device?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically most access points are a bridge. Bridges also operate at the Data-Link layer. A switch is simply a multiport bridge.

They are Data-link layer devices because they use the layer 2 (Data-link) addresses to determine where to forward frames (layer 2 data is called frame, layer 3 data is called packets). More specifically they use the data-link layer address (MAC address for Ethernet) to determine which port the frame should be forwarded.

Any device that operates at one layer also operate at all lower levels. Therefore they can convert from one layer 1 protocol (Ethernet) to another (Wireless).

Comment: For the 3rd paragraph, does it means that AP will change the frame's header when it transfer frame between Ethernet and Wireless? I'm not quite sure what does "convert from one layer protocol to another" mean.....